# How to display name values from nested json structure either using javascript or angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I wanted to display "`name`" values on my html page from my nested json structure, but I am unable to get exactly, I hope I am missing some syntax of it in my `ng-repeat`. Please let me know what I am doing wrong to display the "`name`" values in my table using javascript or angularjs ? I have created [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mR9fOSrW52rAtQYkyogo?p=preview). Thanks in advance.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get("test.json").success(function (response) {
$scope.values = response.test;
console.log(JSON.stringify(response.test));//giving my json data
});
});
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in values">
        <!--<td>{{ item.name }}</td>-->
        <td>{{ item.Testing[0].testval[0].name }}</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

json:

```
{
    "test": [{
        "Testing": {
            "testval": {
                "name": "first name"
            }

        }
    }, {
        "Testing": {
            "testval": {
                "name": "second name"
            }
        }
    }]

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` property can be directly accessing via traversing through the object using `.`(dot) . You don't need to use `[0]` since it isn't an array.

```
<td>{{ item.Testing.testval.name }}</td>
```

[**Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/38c5hV73SmIO84xdl6ki?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes,  it is working fine now.